# How to navigate EULA and MainPage?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

Thanks for your replay. I studied the Introducing the concept of “Places” but frankly speaking i didn't get that thing. I am new to windows phone 7 development so. I will explain how my senior is, in my application i have EULA page which is compulsory to be accepted by the user to use the app. After the EULA is accepted by the user the page is navigated to PhoneNumber.xaml page, here a post is sent to portal along with the phone no., now the page is navigated to MainPage.xaml. And if the user is registered user then don't show the EULA screen just make MainPage.xaml as the  first page of the app. Now, using UriMapper like this,

```
<Application.Resources>
        <UriMapper:UriMapper x:Name="mapper">
            <UriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/MainPage.xaml"/>
        </UriMapper:UriMapper>
    </Application.Resources>

private void SetupUriMapper()
        {
            // Get the UriMapper from the app.xaml resources, and assign it to the root frame
            UriMapper mapper = Resources["mapper"] as UriMapper;
            RootFrame.UriMapper = mapper;
        // Our dummy check -- does the current time have an odd or even number of seconds?
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
        int seconds = time.Second;
        bool isOdd = (seconds % 2) == 1;

        // Update the mapper as appropriate
        if (isOdd)
            mapper.UriMappings[0].MappedUri = new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
        else
            mapper.UriMappings[0].MappedUri = new Uri("/EULA.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
    }
```

Just for testing it is been set to DataTime. Here, the problem is when it comes to EULA.xaml then it navigates to PhoneNumber.xaml then instead of navigating to MainPage.xaml from there it navigating to EULA.xaml. So this is the problem. We are not suppose to use popup for EULA, it should be a page.
Thanks for the help in advance.

Regards,
Panache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to `<UriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/MainOrEULAPage.xaml"/>`

And change WMAppManifest.xml to `<DefaultTask  Name ="_default" NavigationPage="MainOrEULAPage.xaml"/>`

Comment: Hi samwize, Thanks a lot you made my day. Its working, but having some problem when it is navigating back from Mainpage.xaml, the application should end on MainPage.xaml. Any ways i will find out for the back stack navigation to exit the application on MainPage.xaml. Thanks buddy really you made my day. Regards, Panache.

Comment: Hi samwize, i wan you are help, i made the UriMapper changes, its working fine, but when navigating back from main page app should exit, but its navigating to firstpage and EULA too and exits. Will you guide to clear the back stack or how should i exit my app on mainpage.xaml.    Regards, Panache.

Comment: You can "quit" an application, explained here: http://www.imaginativeuniversal.com/blog/post/2010/08/22/How-to-Quit-a-WP7-Silverlight-Application.aspx

Comment: hi samwize i used the way u suggested and gets the things the way i wann but, if app Tombstones then back navigation behaves wired. Please guide me for the same.